# How do I make a route path for hundreds of different articles in React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

First I just want to say that I'm really new to React but I already love using it.

I am trying to create a project where it's much like a reddit clone. I'll have a list component of 100 different articles created with article component with just their titles which are loaded from a JSON file. When I click on each article I would want to just pass that article's id and route to the content component and display just the contents.

How would I make a different page for each article automatically? Like I'd want each article to have a different url address, so if an article has id: 1234, how do I make the extension /1234 ? I read that you should use "/:id" in the router path but how would I make sure that it's a valid ID?

Also, when you click on a specfiic article, how do I pass just that clicked article's ID to the content component?

Comment: I recommend reading a bit about `react-router`, there's even a tutorial: https://github.com/reactjs/react-router-tutorial

Comment: Ok thanks that actually helped a lot. Do you know how I can pass the clicked article's id to my content component? Whenever I press on any article, it always passes the id value of the last rendered article and I dont know how to fix that

Comment: Let's say you have an `Article` component which displays an article by ID. Your route should look something like `<Route path="/article/:articleId" component={Article}/>`. Then your `Article` component can access the article ID with `this.props.params.articleId`